# If statement on Python

Tags: python, if-statement, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
block_id   number_repair  t    lognum                           
2              1.666667  1.0  0.462098
4              4.500000  2.5  1.468807
5              2.750000  1.5  0.895880
7              1.250000  1.5  0.173287
8              4.833333  2.5  1.297204
```

I would like to generate a respective list of 'True' or 'False' value.
If 't' > 2 then return 'true', else return 'false'. How should I write the code to return result like the below?

```
[false true false false true]
```

Comment: What effort have you made so far?

Comment: What version of python?

Comment: map(lambda df: df.t > 2, dtList) should do

Comment: @BlackCat Thanks so much! As I am new to Python and I tried to do some research but still couldn't find the clues. It helps a lot! Thanks

Comment: @joycey Try the python practice challenges in hackerrank, they helped me learn a lot and are also great starting place to learn the pythonic way :)

Comment: @BlackCat: Answers go in the _answer section_ please mate. This isn't a chatroom or message board! Thanks

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit maybe he did not have the time (or want) to flesh out a full answer, explaining why this works...

Comment: @IanS: Then he should leave the posting to someone who does! Comments cannot be reviewed, fully voted, edited, etc. This site has a very specific model and the technology that powers it works best when content is posted in the right place. Comments are for requesting clarification, and flame wars; that's _it_. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
print df.t > 2
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
Name: t, dtype: bool

print (df.t > 2).tolist()
[False, True, False, False, True]
```